# jquery Post not working just in this part of my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show an image by ajax-jquery.

this is part of my html:

```
<div id="searchFormResult1"></div>

<form action="#" method="post" id="searchForm" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" id="searchid" name="searchid" class="searchstu" />
    <input type="submit" value="0" id="searchsubb" class="hidd searchsub" />
    <a href="#" id="link-2" onClick="sear(); return false;"></a>
</form>
```

the div tag is a place for returning php.

my jquery is like this and I put jquery inside the html page:

```
$("#searchsubb").click(function(){
$.post("parts/search.php", {searchid:$("#searchid").val()}, function(data){
    $("#searchFormResult1").html(data).slideDown();
});
});
```

also I have a php page that returning an image html tag:

something like this:

```
print "<img src='' /> and other thing";
```

but my returning value is not receiving.

I dont get any error in my browser and I believe the problem is not from my php.

I receive this error in chrome some times .

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
at J (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:14:142)
at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:17:184)
at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:182
at miscellaneous_bindings:286:9
at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:393:17)
at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:253:22)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your submitting the form at the same time you fire the ajax request.

Add `return false` to prevent the form submission.

```
$("#searchsubb").click(function(){
$.post("parts/search.php", {searchid:$("#searchid").val()}, function(data){
    $("#searchFormResult1").html(data).slideDown();
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: my page refreshed. but nothing happened.

Comment: TNX it worked. I delete return false;  from form submit. and add it into jquery like you said.

Answer (score 0):

the problem must be in php otherwise u would get a response from ajax, 3rd argument from $.post triggers when the ajax gets a response from parts/search.php, try looking in firebug for response tag, if u dont have one is either empty or is not responding